# Appending the Path in an Azure Website to include bin\debug and bin\release

Tags: c#, azure, web-config, azure-web-app-service

It would appear that Azure Websites only look in the `bin` folder for **dlls** and other needed files. I have a *NuGet* package that installs some third party library files to `bin\debug` and `bin\release` (presumably the traditional approach for a non-web application).

However, since Websites only seem to search the `bin` folder, I am trying to learn how to append the `PATH` to tell Azure Websites to also look in `bin\debug` or `bin\release`.

Is there a way to do this via `web.config`?

Comment: there is a way to do it using an xdt transform https://github.com/projectkudu/kudu/wiki/Xdt-transform-samples#adding-environment-variables

Answer (score 2):

There should be nothing special about Azure Web Apps here, as it's just running standard ASP.NET. And generally, ASP.NET will not load managed assemblies from subfolders like `bin\debug`.

Note that sometimes, some *native* binaries get loaded from subfolders, but that's due to custom logic in some managed binaries sitting in `bin`.

You will need to provide more details: what specific NuGet package is it, what exact error are you getting, ...